# Error while configuring AWS SDK in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services, eclipse-plugin, aws-sdk

I am trying to install AWS SDK for my eclipse IDE. But when I install and restart it is giving me this pop-up with bunch of errors.

Internal Error when running initial setup wizard
Internal Error when scanning legacy AWS account configuration
Internal Error when starting the AWS toolkit plugin

And also on closing this, if I go to a particular AWS related tab from Preferences it gives me error.

Currently displayed page contains invalid values.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html

**Go to section "Configuration and Credential Files"**

- Find or create this file: "credentials".
- This file contains empty properties:

```html
[default]
aws_access_key_id=
aws_secret_access_key=
```

---

Set your credentials value and restart eclipse.

- Example:

```html
[default]
aws_access_key_id=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
aws_secret_access_key=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
```

---

*Sorry for my bad english*