# Need help to configure the AWS account information in eclipse neon

Tags: eclipse, amazon-ec2

1. I added the AWS plugin in eclipse neon
2. I restarted the eclipse after plugin installation
3. After restarting the application it’s showing the error screen saying below errors
   a.  Internal error when running initial setup wizard - Internal error when scanning legacy AWS account configuration. java.lang.NullPointerException
   b.  Internal error when scanning legacy AWS account configuration – Internal error when scanning legacy AWS account configuration. java.lang.NullPointerException
   c.  Internal error when starting the AWS Toolkit plugin – Internal error when starting the AWS Toolkit plugin. Unable to load credentials into profile [default]: AWS Access Key ID is not specified.
4. I tried to add the using preference->AWT Toolkit option in window menu. But it’ showing me the error “The display page contains invalid values”

Can someone help me on this?

[Eclipse_AWS_Plugin_Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueqyV.png)

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: This is my solution. ---------- [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39798584/error-while-configuring-aws-sdk-in-eclipse/40245918#40245918](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39798584/error-while-configuring-aws-sdk-in-eclipse/40245918#40245918)

Comment: This is my solution. ---------- [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39798584/error-while-conf‌​iguring-aws-sdk-in-e‌​clipse/40245918#4024‌​5918 ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39798584/error-while-conf%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Biguring-aws-sdk-in-e%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bclipse/40245918#4024%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B5918)